# why SpringBoot not Creating bean for mulitple datasources?

Tags: java, gradle, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

i wanted to use multiple datasources (oracle and sqlserver)in application. 
according to that i have done the configuration.
the code which i have wriiten is like

Configuration file

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource firstDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.secondDasource")
    public DataSource secondDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(firstDataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate sJdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(secondDataSource());
    }
}
```

application.yml file

```
#First                                                                                                                              
spring.datasource.driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver                                                                  
spring.datasource.url: someJdbcUrl                                                                                                  
spring.datasource.username: username                                                                                                
spring.datasource.password: password                                                                                                

#Second                                                                                                                             
spring.secondDatasource.driverClassName: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver                                               
spring.secondDatasource.url: some sqlUrl                                                                                            
spring.secondDatasource.username: username                                                                                          
spring.secondDatasource.password: password
```

Main class

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApp.class, args);
        ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext = SpringApplication.run(MainApp.class, args);
        configurableApplicationContext.start();

        String[] beanNames = configurableApplicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
        System.out.println();

        for (String beanName : beanNames) {

            System.out
                    .println(beanName + " : " + configurableApplicationContext.getBean(beanName).getClass().toString());
        }

        System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

gradle dependancies

```
        compile group: 'sqljdbc4', name: 'sqljdbc4', version: '4.0'
        compile(group: 'ojdbc14', name: 'ojdbc14', version: '10.2.0.5')
```

when i am trying to use second datasource it is throwing exception as its bean has not been created

what i am missing here??

Comment: @Bean
            @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.secoatasource")  Did you mean spring.secondDatasource

Comment: It's still not correct. Follow the doc here http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-two-datasources

Comment: @SouravGanguly I am using the same as mentioned in spring doc. am i missing something??

Answer (score 0):

Try injection via bean names:

```
        @Bean
        public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("firstDataSource") DataSource firstDataSource){
            return new JdbcTemplate(firstDataSource);
        }

        @Bean
        public JdbcTemplate sJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("secondDataSource") DataSource secondDataSource){
            return new JdbcTemplate(secondDataSource);
        }
```